# Isomorphism between $k^3$ and $kC_3$

Tags: representation-theory

I am trying to answer the following question:

Let $G = C_3$ be the cyclic group of order 3, and let $k$ be a field, such that $char(k) \neq 3$ and that $k$ contains a cube root of unity $\omega$. Find an explicit isomorphism of $k$-algebras $k \times k \times k \to kC_3$. I am not really sure where to begin.

Comment: Do you know how to do this for $k \times k \to k[C_2]$, if $\text{char}(k) \neq 2$ (and $k$ contains a primitive square root of unity, namely $-1$, which is automatic)? Once you do, it's like that but more complicated. Try working out all of the possible $k$-algebra homomorphisms $k[C_3] \to k$, then combining them.

Comment: So, for $C_2$ we have that $kC_2$ admits an even-odd decomposition, right? I'm not sure how to extend this to 3 different possibilities, though

Comment: It's a three-way decomposition. You can figure out what it looks like, again, by computing all of the possible $k$-algebra homomorphisms $k[C_3] \to k$.